# How to deal with tibbles when subsetting/indexing dataframe column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, tibble

I am currently subsetting my dataframe column like this `df_subset <- df[,c(2)]`

```
       Measurement
       ------------
1        2752
2        2756
3        2756
4        2740
5        2724
6        2536
7        2796
8        2800
```

The output says this is a 50 x 1 tibble, which makes sense cause there are 50 rows and 1 column. However, I am not sure how to deal with tibbles.  From what I understand I cannot index it like I would a list or vector. Is it easy to index a tibble, and if so how? If not, how would I convert this to a list/vector instead? Just to give you an idea of what I want to do, let's say I want to index the 8th, 15th, 23rd, and 47th measurement values, and I would like the final output to ideally be a vector or something else that is easy to work with.

Comment: `df[c(8,25,23,47),]`?

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helps. So I edited my description, because my wording was confusing. I don't mind working with the tibble directly, but I want to output to be a vector/something easy to work with. Is there anyway to convert what you did to a vector?

Comment: `rows<- c(8, 25, 23, 27)`, then `df[rows, ]`

Comment: You can just convert back to data frame using `as.data.frame()` if the tibble is causing problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a `tibble` is the same as indexing `data.frame`s, except for the fact that `data.frame`s attempt to return the lowest possible dimension, hence the following difference:

```
library(tibble)
df = data.frame(Measurement = c(2752,2756,2756,2740,2724,2536,2796,2800))
df_tib = as.tibble(df)

index = c(2,3,6,7)
```

Indexing dataframe:

```
df[index,]
# [1] 2756 2756 2536 2796

df_tib[index,]
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#   Measurement
#         <dbl>
# 1        2756
# 2        2756
# 3        2536
# 4        2796
```

Notice that `df[index,]` is coerced to a vector after indexing because `data.frame` sees that it is a dataframe with only one column. `tibble` does not make this coercion. To override this property, you can use `drop=FALSE`:

```
df[index,, drop=FALSE]
#   Measurement
# 2        2756
# 3        2756
# 6        2536
# 7        2796
```

To get a vector after indexing, you actually want to index the *column* `Measurement`. This is done exactly the same with either `data.frame` or `tibble`:

```
df$Measurement[index]
# [1] 2756 2756 2536 2796

df_tib$Measurement[index]
# [1] 2756 2756 2536 2796
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for getting a column from a tibble, you can use `pull()`:

```
tb %>% pull(2)
tb %>% pull(Measurement)
```